# Resize UIButtons iPhone 5 to iPhone 6 ratio

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, uibutton, autolayout

[image: Button autolayout]![xcode layout][2]![iphone screens comparison][3]

How do l resize the uiButton proportionaly, the scaling is ok on the iphone 6 and 6 plus. But on the iphone 5 its bloated l don't know how to solve this problem i have tried every thing with auto layout but l don't know where l am getting it wrong.

Comment: We don't know where you're getting it wrong either since you haven't shared any code. Show what you've tried with auto layout.

Comment: Its happening throught the interface builder before writing any code

Comment: how you resized autoresize for autoLayout. share your constriants

Comment: @VineeshTP check my updated image on the button constrainsts

Answer (score 0):

You are getting exactly what you set in the storyboard, in both the send alert button is a square of 160pt. If you want different sizes for elements either you can use the new trait collections to have different layout per device or use relative constraints in your layout.

An example of relative layout would be to have the button horizontally centered same height and width and the width to be a 1/3 of the parent view. That should do for any phone screen.